# What are immutable alternatives for an array in C#?

Tags: c#, immutability

What are immutable alternatives for an array for production code in C# (at least while [ImmutableArray](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/immutable.aspx) is in beta)?

Comment: What's the objective you're trying to achieve? Maybe passing an `IEnumerable` instead of an array could solve your problem?

Comment: I guess arrays are fast in getting the count and reading all the contents in one go (in our specific case they would be located in-memory and accessed by several threads, often containing 10-1000 items each)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should give more details, but one option is `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<>` which acts as a list/array. It can be created like this:

```
  var immutable1 = Array.AsReadOnly(new[] { 7, 9, 13, });
  var immutable2 = (new List<int> { 7, 9, 13, }).AsReadOnly();
```

It is a wrapper around an `IList<>`. It cannot be cast to anything that allows altering the underlying list/array. But the underlying object can be reached with reflection, of course.

If someone somewhere else mutates the "inner" list/array, that will be refelcted in the `ReadOnlyCollection<>` wrapper. No copy is performed.

This is a "shallow" form of immutability. If the individual items can mutate (which an `int` cannot), the wrapper does not prohibit that.

---

A cheaper thing to do is to just use the interface `IReadOnlyList<out T>` which is covariant in `T` (an extra advantage). Both a `List<T>` and a `T[]` implement this interface. So:

```
  IReadOnlyList<int> immutable3 = new[] { 7, 9, 13, };
  IReadOnlyList<int> immutable4 = new List<int> { 7, 9, 13, };
```

In that case, however, the consumer may test `immutable3 as IList<int>`, for example, or `immutable3 as int[]`, and get a "mutable-type reference" to the mutable object (without reflection).

---

However, there are immutable types (such as `ImmutableList<>`) that are not "in beta" in **[Microsoft.Immutable.Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366.aspx)**. So you could consider installing that if you really need it. It is not part of the standard .NET library, so you will have to install it separately.

---

To elaborate on what I mean by "shallow", suppose you have an array whose element type is in itself mutable. Then no matter which of the suggestions above you use, people can still modyfy the entries. For example:

```
StringBuilder[] yourArray = { 
    new StringBuilder("All"),
    new StringBuilder("is"),
    new StringBuilder("good"),
    };

var immutable = ImmutableList<StringBuilder>.Empty.AddRange(yourArray);

immutable[0].Insert(0, "NOT ");
immutable[1].Clear();
immutable[2].Append(new string('!', 10000));
```

Comment: Also, note that the readonly collection is not a copy itself. So you must make sure the underlying list / array isn't leaked out, because that would mutate the readonly wrapper as well.

Comment: The Immutable Collections NuGet package *is* still beta (or at least RC status): "System.Collections.Immutable 1.1.34**-rc**"

Comment: @Brandon I guess I do not know what release terminology is used by Microsoft, and I do not know what _beta_ means. Sorry about that. But if you read [Immutable collections ready for prime time](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time.aspx) they say they "released a stable version" and that this is "ready for prime time". From summary: _We’ve just shipped a stable release of `Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable`. The license now allows usage in production, so they are ready for prime time._

Comment: @Jeppe ImmutableArray has been removed from the currently stable release: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/12/immutable-collections-are-now-rc.aspx

Comment: @thomius I agree! So I mentioned `ImmutableList<>` for that reason. It seems to be "released" and might be an answer to the poster's vague inquiry for an "alternative" to `ImmutableArray<>`. In fact I think I provided quite many alternatives, given the lack of details in the question.

Comment: Yes my bad, read it wrong first. Nevertheless nice answer and well deserved +1 and accept mark :)

Comment: @RBT Maybe different people use different terminology. Microsoft seems to use the word read-only for collections that __do not publicly expose__ methods that can modify the collection. However, the collection could still change "by itself" because someone has access to the "backing" storage. On the other hand they use the word immutable for collections (in `System.Collections.Immutable`) that can truly never change. Nobody said "immutable" and "read-only" was the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage to the just using `ReadOnlyCollection` or `IReadOnlyList` is that these provide much weaker guarantees than an immutable array.  These objects only guarantee that the holder of the read only collection will not modify it.  They do not guarantee that the collection won't be modified by code that holds a reference to the underlying collection.

Specifically, the consumer of such an object must still employ thread synchronization while reading from the collection, because there is no guarantee that the owner of the underlying collection is not busy adding/removing items from the collection when you are reading it through your read-only lense.  Or you have to have a documented agreement between the consumer and producer that the collection won't be modified.

If you really want an immutable array and you cannot use the Immutable Collections package for some reason, then just make sure the source never modifies the array, but instead clones it whenever it wants to make a change.  Combine this with handing out "read only" handles to implement immutable arrays.

LINQ makes it pretty easy to implement your own, though it is not terribly smart.  An example of removing one item in an array with another in an immutable way:

```
private int[] _array;

public void RemoveItem(int item)
{
    _array = _array.Where(x => x != item).ToArray();
}

/// <summary>Gets immutable array</summary>
public IReadOnlyList<int> Data { get { return _array; } }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info :) I guess ImmutableList would be the best choice by now.

Comment: A way to cope with that concern is to copy the entire list/array and then wrap the _copy_ in a `ReadOnlyCollection<>` (or upcast the copy to `IReadOnlyList<>`). If you write it like `var safe = originalArray.ToList().AsReadOnly();` you can be sure that no-one has a reference to the intermediate `List<>` created (because you do not keep that reference).